# How to concatenate a string with a variable to include an image

Tags: php, concatenation

```
for($i ; $i < $rowcount ; $i++){
    /*here i want to add an image to my page.*/
    echo"<li class='streep mix'><img src='img/'".$productnaam."'.jpg'\>
        <button>
            <i class='fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </button>
        </li>";
        echo"<li class='gap'></li>";
}
```

i dont understand how to concatenate the image part

Comment: Add another echo perhaps? Or do it just like you're `.` concatenating your `$productnaam` variable there. Not clear what exactly is unclear here.

Comment: Was the Variable `$productnaam` already pre-declared? Does it exists already or would it be generated within your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
echo "<li class='streep mix'><img src='img/" . $productnaam . ".jpg'\>";
echo "<button>";
echo "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
echo "</button>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='gap'></li>";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Error is here: `echo "<li class='streep mix'><img src='img/'" . $productnaam . "'.jpg'\>";` Your code still wouldn't fix it because it is not taking the quotes into consideration. Revisit your code and check the Quotes.... the Single-Quote Marks..... There is were the Error was....

Comment: @Poiz : There was an extra single quote. I have edited that, please chaeck now.....

Comment: ... Now it's **Perfect!!!** @NewbieJavaDeveloper! Awesome!!! An **Up** for that extra-effort ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Most probably; You are looking for something like this:

```
    <?php

    // OBSERVE THE PART:  <img src='img/" . $productnaam . ".jpg' />   
    // AS WELL AS THE FORWARD SLASH BEFORE CLOSING THE <IMG /> TAG  
    echo"<li class='streep mix'><img src='img/" . $productnaam . ".jpg' />
        <button>
            <i class='fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </button>
        </li>";
    echo"<li class='gap'></li>";
```

> However, It would be ideal for you (*at this stage*) to build up your *Output-String* in sequences so that you could easily spot any typos or potential quote-related errors without much fuss.

```
<?php

    $output = "";

    for($i; $i < $rowcount; $i++){
        // EMBED AN IMAGE WITHIN A LIST ITEM
        $output .= "<li class='streep mix'>";
        $output .= "<img src='img/{$productnaam}.jpg' />";  //<== FORWARD SLASH HERE

        // THEN, ADD THE SHOPPING-CART BUTTON
        $output .= "<button>";
        $output .= "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
        $output .= "</button>";
        $output .= "</li>";
        $output .= "<li class='gap'></li>";
    }

    echo $output;
```